# Where can I find this Gronwall's inequality proof?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm looking for a proof of the following result:

Let I denote an interval of the real line of the form $[a,b]$ with $ a<b $. Let $\beta$ and $u$ be real-valued continuous functions defined on I. If $u$ is differentiable in the interior of I and satisfies, for all $t \in I^o$
$$
u'(t) \leq u(t)\beta(t),
$$
then u also satisfies
$$
u(t) \leq u(a)exp(\int^t_a\beta(s)ds)
$$
for all $t \in I$.

It's basically a summarized version of the one appearing if you look for Gronwall's inequality on wikipedia. I'd like to find it somewhere else so I could understand it better, also I'd need a good reference since I'm in need of this result for an assignement. I've tried and tried googling it yet all I find are proofs of the integral form. Could someone tell me of a good article/book where I could find it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of citing it, you can verify it yourself using an integrating factor. $$\left(e^{-\int_a^t β(s)ds}u(t)\right)'=e^{-\int_a^t β(s)ds}(u'(t)-β(t)u(t))\le 0$$ and integrate both sides, the integral is order-preserving.

Comment: It's true it is quite straight forward and easy to proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might try:

E. Coddington & N. Levinson, Theory of ordinary differential equations,
McGraw-Hill, 1955.

A copy of a paper on its proof is given here (where the above reference was cited)

https://www.math.wisc.edu/~robbin/angelic/gronwall.pdf

Also, check out

[Any other proof for the Gronwall's inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276309/any-other-proof-for-the-gronwalls-inequality)

Hope this helps.